# SonarQube Eclipse plugin doesn't follow Eclipse links, and "sonar.sources" must be relative path

Tags: eclipse, plugins, sonarqube, analysis

- Eclipse: "Luna" Release 2 (4.4.2) [20150219-0600]
- Sonar: 5.1 (under Java 1.7.0_76)
- Sonar Eclipse plugin: 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE

We have a large Enterprise system with many projects, and for various non-negotiable reasons we create our Eclipse projects in a local workspace directory but use Eclipse links to point to the sources in another directory.

For example, assume that my Foo project is based in "C:/EclipseWorkspace/Foo" and has an "src" link at the top level like this:

```
 C:/EclipseWorkspace/Foo/src -> C:/CodeRepository/Foo/src
```

I wanted to have the following very simple setup for the plugin:

```
 sonar.sources = C:/CodeRepository/Foo/src
```

**The problem is, the Sonar Eclipse plugin does not appear to support using an absolute path.**  When I run an analysis I get the following error on the console:

```
Retrieve remote issues of project Foo...
Start SonarQube analysis on Foo...
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1
17:16:18.565 INFO  - Incremental mode
17:16:18.609 INFO  - Load global repositories
17:16:18.862 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=253ms
17:16:18.863 INFO  - Server id: 20150910100331
17:16:18.865 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\eryq\.sonar\cache
17:16:18.870 INFO  - Install plugins
17:16:18.894 INFO  - Include plugins: 
17:16:18.894 INFO  - Exclude plugins: devcockpit, buildstability, pdfreport, report, buildbreaker, views, jira
17:16:19.375 ERROR - Invalid value of sonar.sources for Foo
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar 
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The folder 'C:/CodeRepository/Foo/src' does not exist for 'Foo' (base directory = C:\EclipseWorkspace\Foo)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.checkExistenceOfPaths(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:427)
    at ...
```

Notice that last line:

> The folder 'C:/CodeRepository/Foo/src' does not exist for 'Foo' (base
>   directory = C:\EclipseWorkspace\Foo)

Since the Eclipse plugin does not allow me to override the **projectBaseDir**, how do I make it understand that the **sonar.sources** are actually in another directory outside that tree?  This seems like a plugin bug: if I need to point to a list of *sources* directories, the plugin should let me specify absolute paths if needed.

Thanks in advance,

Eryq

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to SonarQube Eclipse and not related to absolute path: any SonarQube analysis requires to have source folders located under the project baseDir.

Allowing you to override `sonar.projectBaseDir` is an easy fix. But I'm not sure this would not lead to other issues later when issues are mapped to Eclipse resources... Feel free to test and submit a pull request.

Comment: Julien, are you the plugin developer? I've never worked on Eclipse plugins before, and I don't exactly have the time to investigate this. If it's an easy fix, can you do us a favor and simply allow it?   Also, I don't understand why Sonar would restrict the "sources" directory list in such a fashion: this seems like Sonar being "too smart for its own good".  :-)  If a user is going through the trouble of specifying a "sources" directory list, it should assume they are doing so for a reason.

Comment: Yes, I am the lead developer on this plugin. Concerning the limitation of source there are some good reasons: in DB the identifier of a file is the relative path from project baseDir. Also the UI expose project content as a tree starting from basedir. Having files outside of this basedir would not fit this model.

Comment: I completely understand the need to identify Sonar components uniquely by relative paths.  In our case, the relative paths are absolutely identical.  It's just that right now most of our Enterprise is still using ClearCase for source code control, and for various reasons we don't want the Eclipse project's top level directory to be a ClearCase directory.  Eclipse links make this configuration possible, but they break Sonar's plugin.  As we migrate to Git this issue should go away, but that will take time.  :-(